# Graphical asset-select for Safecracker

Tags: safecracker, assets

I want to give my client the ability to visually select a file from one of my file-folders in safecracker. I was thinking of using an embed with `{exp:assets:files}` loop in there, something along these lines:

```
{exp:assets:files folder_id='1' kind='image'}
    <li><a href="#" data-url="{url}"><img src="{url}" alt="{filename}"></a></li>
{/exp:assets:files}
```

Now what would I feed back to the safecracker-form in order for my assets-field in this entry to be updated with the file I just clicked? Should I feed the file's url to a hidden `<input>` element?

Thanks,

- Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently there's no way to do what you want that I can think of, but I like the idea. Seeing as we have Assets 2.1 in development, I'll have a chat with Brandon and we'll see what we can come up with to make you happy.

Cheers,
Andris

Comment: I think implementation-wise this would ideally work by filling an `<input type="hidden" name="my_custom_field[id]" value="{asset_id}">` with the file-id. Is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: Steven, this is how it's working at the moment, yeah :)

Comment: What do you mean? Can I do this already?

Comment: Nope - that's how it's working on my Assets build at the moment :p As soon as I get the remaning stuff for Assets 2.1 in order, you'll be able to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably going to be a bit more complex than that. Assets may be doing that work with JavaScript rather than just routing a selected file to a field.

I would recommend opening up Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome or Safari, and instantiating a full-blown Assets field in your Safecracker template. You can then see:

- The HTML it generates for the dynamic form field
- The JavaScript references and any inline script it bundles into the form
- What happens when you actually select a file and where that's stored until the form is submitted

You'll then have a sense of what you need to reproduce on your end to accomplish your goal.

I've never done this with Assets. We've done it with Matrix, where it's just a matter of adding sets of form fields with a `new` fieldname convention. I suspect Assets is going to go a little deeper, though.

Comment: I understand that, since version 2.0 however assets also has the ability to do uploads in Safecracker with just a simple html file-input, so I thought there'd be a semi-easy way to do this...

Comment: I wasn't aware of that and it doesn't look like there's much in their docs. The P&T team will have to chime in and top my answer :)

Comment: Lucky for me they've been known to roam these parts (read: StackExchange is their official support now :) )